# How to match up to and including a condition with Regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have data formatted as a string of 1s and 0s, similar to the following:

```
string <- c("110010100010101000000011100101")
```

From it, I want to extract all mutually exclusive strings that:

- Start with a 1
- Have any number of characters UNTIL and INCLUDING...
- ...a sequence of up to 5 0s

So for the string I presented above, using `str_extract_all()`, I want the output to look like:

```
[1] "11001010001010100000" "11100101"
```

Instead, I get:

```
> str_extract_all(string,"1(\\d+)(0{0,10})")
[[1]]
[1] "110010100010101000000011100101"
```

How might I edit the R regex expression to achieve this goal? Could this be done using grep functions in R instead of stringr?

Comment: Maybe you want `1.*?(?:0{5,}|$)`?

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(stringr)

string <- c("110010100010101000000011100101")

str_extract_all(string, '1[0-1]*?(0{5}|$)')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "11001010001010100000" "11100101"
```

Comment: Thank you! You would not believe how many hours I spent trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Actually, I think that the +? needs to be a *?, but otherwise this solutions works!